# Declare a JSON array of Objects and add items dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is stupid but i am missing something and could not reach the conclusion.
I am trying to initialize a JSON Array and trying to add JSON Objects to it run time.
For an example, I will be getting the list of repeated values from server something like below.

```
"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

I have to create an array of object and fill these values in it.

I am trying to initialize an array like

```
var myArr = [];
```

and I want to add object with properties to it dynamically, something like below.

```
var myobj = {}

for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
myobj[i].name = serverrespOBJ.name;
myobj[i].lastName= 'serverrespOBJ.lastname';
myArr.push(myobj)
}
```

I am getting the error that **name** can not be added to undefined, so i believe, my way of adding items to the object is incorrect.

I am trying to find a good example but could not get it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should pick a correct answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll be wanting something like this:

```
var data = { employees: [] }   // initially empty

data.employees.push( {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
} );
```

Comment: @Gendaful no, please don't do that, it invalidates answers already provided.

Comment: @Gendaful in any event, your problem is that you need to create `myobj` _inside_ the loop, otherwise you're just adding the same object to the array over and over.  You also need to lose the `[i]` dereference - `myobj` is an object, not an array.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak, So in short, I am creating an array myArr and then creating myObj inside for loop such as myObj = {}. After that, I am adding the items such as myobj.name = 'abc, myobj.lastname = def etc. and then adding the obj to the array like myarr.push(myobj), but whenever I am trying to retrieve it with myarray[0].name, it always returns undefined, what do you think I am missing here?

Comment: @Gendaful perhaps the source data you're trying to put _into_ `myObj` is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You can init a new json object like this:

```
var jsonObj = {};
jsonObj.employees = [];
jsonObj.employees.push({"firstName":"Waqar", "lastName":"Alamgir"});
```

or add data in existance like this:

```
var jsonObj = {
    "employees":[
        {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
        {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
        {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
    ]
};

jsonObj.employees.push({"firstName":"Waqar", "lastName":"Alamgir"});

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: This is a valid JSON!

Comment: No, it isn't.  JSON is a _string serialisation format_.  What you have is a JS _object literal_.

Comment: The one you are talking about is array JSON encoded, user is asking about JSON array!!

Comment: No, there's _no such thing_ as a "JSON array".  There _are_ "arrays encoded in JSON format".  No such entity appears in the question, nor in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple init first the object or array you want to play dynamicly e.x:

```
var myArr = [], myObj = {};
```

Now if adding element to them:

```
myArr.push(10);
myObj.new = 10 or myObj['new'] = 10
```

More advanced :

```
myArr.push(myObj); //[10, {'new':10}] --> looks our object
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FamBn/1/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" />
<input type="text" id="lastname" />
<input type="submit" id="add" />
<div id="dsp"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var employees=[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
];

$('#add').click(function(){
    var fname=$('#firstname').val();
    var lname=$('#lastname').val();
    employees.push({
        firstName: fname,
        lastName: lname
    });
    var output = '';
    for (var i=0; i<employees.length; i++) {
        output += "FirstName: " + employees[i].firstName + " LastName: " + employees[i].lastName;
    }
    $('#dsp').html(output);
    console.log(employees);
});
```